# Using the sh step on Windows

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**TL;DR** *I want to use the `sh` step even though Jenkins is running on Windows. I do not want to use the `bat` step, unless you can show me how to easily reproduce what I need done using `bat`*

I've been converting some old Jenkins jobs over to 2.x Pipeline script. One of my jobs uses the "Publish over SSH plugin" to:

- Send artifacts to a remote server
- Exec a set of commands on the remote server

For instance:

[image: Publish over SSH plugin]

I wanted to replicate this in Pipeline Script so I've done the following:

```
   stage('Deploy') {
    withCredentials([[$class: 'FileBinding', credentialsId: 'bitbucket-key-file', variable: 'SSHKEY']]) {
        sh '''
            scp -i "$SSHKEY" dsub.tar.gz tprmbbuild@192.168.220.57:dsubdeploy
            scp -i "$SSHKEY" deployDsubUi.sh tprmbbuild@192.168.220.57:dsubdeploy
            ssh -i "$SSHKEY" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 192.168.220.57 <<- EOF
                DEPLOY_DIR=/home/tprmbbuild/dsubdeploy
                echo '*** dos2unix using sed'
                sed -e 's/\r$//' $DEPLOY_DIR/deployDsubUi.sh > $DEPLOY_DIR/deployDsubUi-new.sh
                mv $DEPLOY_DIR/deployDsubUi-new.sh $DEPLOY_DIR/deployDsubUi.sh
                chmod 755 $DEPLOY_DIR/deployDsubUi.sh
                echo '*** Deploying Dsub UI'
                $DEPLOY_DIR/deployDsubUi.sh $DEPLOY_DIR/dsub.tar.gz
            EOF'''
    }
   }
```

Problem is, I get this stack trace when executing my build:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[E:\Jenkins\jenkins_home\workspace\tpr-ereg-ui-deploy@2] Running shell script
      1 [main] sh 3588 E:\Jenkins\tools\Git_2.10.1\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - add_item ("\??\E:\Jenkins\tools\Git_2.10.1", "/", ...) failed, errno 1
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
000FFFF9BB0  0018005C24E (0018023F612, 0018021CC39, 000FFFF9BB0, 000FFFF8B30)
000FFFF9BB0  001800464B9 (000FFFFABEE, 000FFFF9BB0, 1D2345683BEC046, 00000000000)
000FFFF9BB0  001800464F2 (000FFFF9BB0, 00000000001, 000FFFF9BB0, 4A5C3A455C3F3F5C)
000FFFF9BB0  001800CAA8B (00000000000, 000FFFFCE00, 001800BA558, 1D234568CAFA549)
000FFFFCC00  00180118745 (00000000000, 00000000000, 001800B2C5E, 00000000000)
000FFFFCCC0  00180046AE5 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  00180045753 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFF0  00180045804 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
End of stack trace
```

Comment: Is this relevant to you? http://www.tikalk.com/devops/shell-jenkins-windows-slave/

Comment: The output doesn't show `"*** dos2unix using sed"`. It may have failed in `scp` or it may have failed in starting up the shell. If you could add `echo` command after each scp, that may give you a hint. Also you could try to run an empty shell script (with just `echo`) to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @blackpen actually it is my belief it is failing to spawn the shell, so none of the commands get a chance to run

Comment: @NateGardner have that configured already, to no avail :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run the scp.exe from the git installation directly within a batch script. 
There is no "here" document for batch as far as I know, but you could just put the script to be run on the server into a separate file.

(Untested)

```
stage('Deploy') {
withCredentials([[$class: 'FileBinding', credentialsId: 'bitbucket-key-file', variable: 'SSHKEY']]) {
    bat '''
        E:\\Jenkins\\tools\\Git_2.10.1\\usr\\bin\\scp.exe -i "${SSHKEY}" dsub.tar.gz tprmbbuild@192.168.220.57:dsubdeploy
        E:\\Jenkins\\tools\\Git_2.10.1\\usr\\bin\\scp.exe -i "${SSHKEY}" deployDsubUi.sh tprmbbuild@192.168.220.57:dsubdeploy
        E:\\Jenkins\\tools\\Git_2.10.1\\usr\\bin\\scp.exe -i "${SSHKEY}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 192.168.220.57 < server_script.sh
}
```

}

Comment: I'm disappointed though that something I could quite easily do with v1.6 plugins is so complicated or not even possible to do with 2.x pipeline script

Answer (score 4):

Agreed with "it is my belief it is failing to spawn the shell". It is trying to run "E:\Jenkins\tools\Git_2.10.1\usr\bin\sh.exe" (using Windows backslash syntax). Unless we have a shell executable configured (sh.exe) in the mentioned directory, it will fail.

**Powershell (or Cmd Shell):**
If you are oepn to use batch files, you would have to install/configure 3 binaries (ssh, scp, ssh). Everything else falls in place (I see that you are channeling commands to a remote machine using ssh. I assume that the remote server is linux/unix based).

**Alternatives**:
You can use cygwin or run linux on virtualbox (or any software that emulates linux on windows). But, running just 3 commands may not be worth the trouble (It will definitely be fruitful if you have plans to convert/write more shell scripts in future).

Comment: @ThaDon, Thanks for awarding the bounty. If you need clarifications, I would be happy to help you.

Comment: So are you saying I have to set `%PATH%`? And btw in your 3 binaries you mentioned `ssh` twice

Answer (score 3):

You can use "bat" instead of "sh" in windows.
Also use 2 backslashes to escape the path string correctly. See example below

```
  node {
      currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
      try {

       stage('Checkout'){

          checkout scm
       }

       stage('Convert to Binary RPD'){
         bat "D:\\oracle\\Middleware\\user_projects\\domains\\bi\\bitools\\bin\\biserverxmlexec -D .\\RPD -P Gl081Reporting -O .\\GLOBI.rpd"
       }


       stage('Notify'){

         echo 'sending email'

         // send to email
           emailext ( 
               subject: "SUCCESS: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'", 
               body: """$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS:
                    Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results.""",
               to:"girish.lakshmanan@abc.co.uk girish.la@gmail.com"
            )
       }

    }
    catch (err) {

        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"

        throw err
    }

}
```