sh 'npm install' cmd not working in jenkins pipeline. Note: jenkins is installed inside windows
I am writing a simple jenkins files to test, build and deploy angular application.
but my jenkins pipeline is failing at sh 'npm install'
Here is my jenkins pipeline script
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/0APOCALYPSE0/ngrx-task.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'ng test'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
          steps {
            sh 'ng build'
          }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                bat 'move dist\\ngrx-task\\*.* C:\\nginx\\'
            }
        }
    }
}

I am also attaching the screenshot of the error:

error:
Found unhandled java.io.IOException exception:
Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Angular build and deploy"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1170)
    java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1089)
    hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:252)
    hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:221)
    hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:994)
    hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:506)
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:180)
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:134)
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:329)
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:323)
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)

I tried googling but I am not able to find the solution. I am new to jenkins/devops. I think there is something wrong with sh cmd maybe jenkins in installed in windows that is why it is not able to run sh cmd.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

There's a bat step for windows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363621/using-the-sh-step-on-windows

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas so you are saying if I'll replace sh keyword with bat then it will work?

bat like "batch script" (as opposed to sh script for linux.) There's syntax differences. I'm just saying that, as you pointed out, you're running on Windows. npm install works in a batch script, so I would be somewhat confident it would just work in a bat block in Jenkins-on-Windows.

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas it is working after replacing sh with bat thanks

I suppose you are running the default agent wish is the Built-In Node wish is not recommended, you have to set up agent either a windows agent (in wish you will have to use PowerShell "bat") or set up a Linux agent wish uses "sh".
An agent could be a virtual machine, a raspberry pie or a remote server, anything with a command line.
This is a guide on how to set up a Linux virtual machine agent on youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99DddJiH7lM&t=403s&ab_channel=CloudBeesTV
and the agent documentation
furthermore, you will have to have Node.js installed on it and in path.
Alternatively, you can use docker containers as agent you will need docker to be installed and in path
Refer to the Docker with Pipeline doc :
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/
exp :
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:20.16.0-alpine3.20' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}


Can you explain about powershell bat? Actually I don't want to install Jenkins in Linux agent. I want to run Jenkins in windows only.

I never used bat and don't know how to. And you don't have to install Jenkins in a Linux, you just need to connect it to a Linux with an ssh credential like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99DddJiH7lM&t=403s&ab_channel=CloudBeesTV. If you are familiar with docker, you can use docker images as agents as I mentioned (you have to install docker Jenkins plugin)

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/419705/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas
for a suggestion. After replacing sh keyword with bat my jenkins pipeline is working fine.
Here is the updated file:
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/0APOCALYPSE0/ngrx-task.git'
      }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        bat 'npm install'
        bat 'npm run ng test'
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        bat 'npm run ng build'
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        bat 'move dist\\ngrx-task\\*.* C:\\nginx\\'
      }
    }
  }
}

